# Add IF statement to JSP

Tags: html, jsp, if-statement

I am trying to add an if statement to following code, but it keeps throwing errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
     <%
      int countOnRows = 0;
        int i;
        countOnRows=  Integer.parseInt(formFields.getValue("broughtBack"));
        if (countOnRows = 0) {
        <h2>No data available - check back later </h2>
        }

        for( i=1; i<=countOnRows; i++ )
        { %>
                <div class="a_report">

                <h2>Dealer Sales Report</h2>

                <h3>Sales Results as of July 2014 - <%=formFields.getValue("dealerName"+i)%>, Dealer <span class="dlr_info"># <%=formFields.getValue("dealerNo"+i)%></span></h3>

                <div class="body_copy"><span class="print">[ <a href="javascript:window.print()">print this report</a> ]</span>
    :
    : table with table data in report here
    :

    <% } %>

            </div>
```

Comment: init i is not a number

Answer (score 0):

It is not Java code:

```
if (countOnRows = 0) {
    <h2>No data available - check back later </h2>
}
```

change it into:

```
if (countOnRows == 0) {
    %> <h2>No data available - check back later </h2> <%
}
```

I also changed `if (countOnRows = 0)` into `if (countOnRows == 0)`

You should read about using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) and [EL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm), it's better than using Java code inside JSP pages.